# Checking form submission for minimum and maximum quantities

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

Working with an existing script that checks input values on form submission against existence of minimum quantity. I need to include a condition to check for the existence of maximum quantity and display an error message when the condition is not met. I believe it's a matter of editing the existing conditional logic but for the life of me I cannot get the edits to function without hosing up the functioning minimum condition. Rather than submitting my failed attempt at altering the code I'm submitting a functional version that only validates minimum quantities.

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    var total_quantity = 0;
    var min_oneside = parseInt("<?php echo $min_oneside; ?>");
    var min_bothside = parseInt("<?php echo $min_bothside; ?>");
    var min_noprint = parseInt("<?php echo $min_noprint; ?>");
    var min_standard = parseInt(" <?php echo $minimum; ?>");
    var max_standard = parseInt(" <?php echo $maximum; ?>");
    var validQty = true;
    var validMaxQty = true;
    var validInput = true;      
    var oth_minimum = "Quantity must be at least <?php echo $minimum; ?>";
    var oth_maximum = "Quantity must be less than <?php echo $maximum; ?>"

    $('#content').find('input[name^="option-quantity"]').each(function(){
            total_quantity = total_quantity + parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('#content').find('input[name="quantity"]').each(function(){
            total_quantity = total_quantity + parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    var element = $("label:contains('Printing')").attr('for');
    if(element === undefined){
        if( total_quantity < min_standard ) {
            validQty = false;
            validInput = false;
            oth_minimum = "Quantity must be at least " + min_standard;
        }else if (total_quantity > max_standard){
            validQty = false;
            validInput = false;
            oth_message = oth_maximum;
            }
    } else {
        if ( ($("#" + element + " option:selected").text()).match("Printed One Side") ){
            if( total_quantity < min_oneside ) {
                validQty = false;
                validInput = false;
                oth_minimum = "Quantity must be at least " + min_oneside;
            }else if (total_quantity > max_standard){
                validQty = false;
                validInput = false;
                oth_message = oth_maximum;
            }
        }
        if ( ($("#" + element + " option:selected").text()).match("Printed Both Sides") ){
            if( total_quantity < min_bothside ) {
                validQty = false;
                validInput = false;
                oth_minimum = "Quantity must be at least " + min_bothside;
            }else if (total_quantity > max_standard){
                validQty = false;
                validInput = false;
                oth_message = oth_maximum;
            }
        }
        if ( ($("#" + element + " option:selected").text()).match("No Printing") ){
            if( total_quantity < min_noprint ) {
                validQty = false;
                validInput = false;
                oth_minimum = "Quantity must be at least " + min_noprint;
            }else if (total_quantity > max_standard){
                validQty = false;
                validInput = false;
                oth_message = oth_maximum;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!validQty) {
        $('#errorQuantity').html(oth_minimum);
    }
    var minimum = "Quantity must be at least <?php echo $minimum; ?>";
    if($('#errorQuantity').length > 0 && validQty) {
        var quantity = 0;
        $('#errorQuantity').empty();
        $('input[type=number]').each(function () {
            var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
            checkboxId = currentId.replace("quantity-", "");
            if(isNaN($(this).val()) || $(this).val() < 0) {
                $(this).focus();
                $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
                validInput = false;
            } else {
                quantity += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });
        if(quantity <= 0) {
            $('#errorQuantity').append(minimum);
            validInput = false;
        }
    }
    if(validInput){
        $('input[type=number]').each(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
        });
        $('#errorQuantity').empty();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
            type: 'post',
            data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'number\'], .product-info input[type=\'date\'], .product-info input[type=\'datetime\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#button-cart').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#button-cart').after('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');
            },
            success: function(json) {
                $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                $('#button-cart').next('.fa-spin').remove();
                $('#button-cart').attr('disabled', false);
                if (json['error']) {
                    var errors = '';
                    if (json['error']['option']) {
                        for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                            var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));
                            element.parents('.form-group').first().find('> label + div').append('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                        }
                    }
                if (json['error']['recurring']) {
                    $('select[name="recurring_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</span>');
                }
                // Highlight any found errors
                $('.text-danger').each(function() {
                    $(this).parents('.form-group').first().addClass('has-error');
                });
            }
            if (json['success']) {
                $('.tb_widget_cart > .tb_nav').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info .tb_nav > *');
                window.location = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=checkout/cart';
                //displayNotice('product', 'success', 'product', json['success']);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a number is not lower than a certain minimum number?

Comment: As it stands, the logic will check to see if the input is < $minimum. I need to include logic to also check if input is  > $maximum, if so display an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like :

```
    if(element === undefined){
    if( total_quantity < min_standard ) {
        validQty = false;
        validInput = false;
        oth_message = oth_minimum;
    }else if (total_quantity > max_standard){
        validQty = false;
        validInput = false;
        oth_message = oth_maximum;
    }
} else {
    if ( ($("#" + element + " option:selected").text()).match("Printed One Side") ){
        if( total_quantity < min_oneside ) {
            validQty = false;
            validInput = false;
            oth_message = "Quantity must be at least " + min_oneside;
        }
    }
    if ( ($("#" + element + " option:selected").text()).match("Printed Both Sides") ){
        if( total_quantity < min_bothside ) {
            validQty = false;
            validInput = false;
            oth_message = "Quantity must be at least " + min_bothside;
        }
    }
    if ( ($("#" + element + " option:selected").text()).match("No Printing") ){
        if( total_quantity < min_noprint ) {
            validQty = false;
            validInput = false;
            oth_message = "Quantity must be at least " + min_noprint;
        }
    }
}
if(!validQty) {
    $('#errorQuantity').html(oth_message);
}
```

You can add in the same way for the other conditionals, I added only for the first one.

Comment: I included the remaining conditions. in instances where a minimum has been specified, an error message is displayed when the minimum has not been satisfied, and when the minimum has been met another error is displayed that stating "a minimum of 1 must be ordered." [Check out this page for a visual](http://idiskey.com/mfgservs2/grocery-bag-carrier). I think the condition if($('#errorQuantity').length > 0 && validQty) also needs to be updated to display the correct message?

Comment: I updated the code to include feedback from @TiberiuPopescu

Comment: As I can see the value for **max_standard** that comes from **php** it is 0.
Probably that's why.